# Doubt about the diagonalization of a state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, group-theory, linear-algebra

I'm studing the unitary irreducible representations of the deSitter group in two dimension.The generators of its double cover, the group $SL(2,R)$, are the following
$$
H_2 = \frac{\sigma_2}{2} \\
F_1 = \frac{i \sigma_1}{2} \\
F_3 = \frac{i \sigma_3}{2},
$$
where the $\sigma$'s are the Pauli matrices.
The Casimir of the group is
$$
I = H_2^2 - F_1^2 - F_3^2,
$$
which for the so called "principal series" takes the values
$$
I | \Delta > = \Delta(\Delta + 1) |\Delta> \qquad \Delta \in \frac{1}{2}(1+ i\gamma) \qquad \gamma \in R .
$$
Now if we want to diagonalize this state respect to the operator $H_2$ we find that
$$
H_2 | \Delta, n> = n |\Delta, n> \qquad n \in Z/2,
$$
but how do we find the action $F_1 |\Delta, n>$ and $F_3 |\Delta, n>$?
Moreover if we want to diagonalize another operator, let's say $F_3$, and so we have
$$
F_3 | \Delta, \eta> = \eta | \Delta, \eta> \qquad \eta \in R,
$$
how do we find the actions of the others operators?

Comment: Really?  The normalization of the third generator is 3? Have you looked at the unitary transforms of the generators?

Comment: No it's 2, it's a typo.